# Getting indexes of all max values in a list

Tags: python

Is there any way in Python to get all indexes of elements which contain max value of a list?

I've tried this:

```
list = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]
m = list.index (max(list))
```

But this returns only the first index of all of those which have max value.

Comment: Avoid assigning variable name as `list`.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously do, just changed a name to clarify my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
l = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]
mx = max(l)
m = [i for i,j in enumerate(l) if j==mx]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[1, 8, 13, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the `max` then use a list comprehension to get the indices where the `max` is found:

```
l = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3]
x = max(l)

m = [i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] == x]

print(m)
```

Output:

```
[1, 8, 13, 16]
```